# UITableView remove multiple row in multiple sections and save to .plist

Tags: ios, uitableview

There have been lots of great answers on Stack overflow about this topic but I cant find anything specific enough to my cause so I will ask you guys for your help.

I have a TableView which access a .plist of information. The information in the .plist is sorted into Arrays of Dictionaries. So section 1 may have 3 dictionaries of info and section 2 may have 4...

What I need to do is be able to select multiple rows in the tableView (which is already set up) and then delete the rows from the tableView (which is also set up), but I cannot seem remove and update the .plist without it crashing. Here is my code below:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (self.tableView.isEditing)
    {
        _rowsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]];
 }
```

Inside of the DeleteRows method I have tried a number of actions but basically I need to access the .plist again and remove the selected index's from the tableView and re-save the .plist.

The best result I have got so far is that I can delete multiple rows inside of one section however selecting multiple rows in multiple sections crashes. One answer suggested using a Case: by Case: situation on each section however the number of sections changes dynamically.

I apologise for the lack of information around the exact code used etc... but I am hoping someone can suggest the best solution for this kind of scenario.

Thanks in advanced, T

Comment: Can you share the link to the answers where they have told you how to delete multiple rows from different sections to avoid crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// This method will be called for each cell you have tapped
// You cant write here any code for deletion here 
}
```

Instead try below mentioned approach - this works for single cell deletion

However you can deleteRowsAtIndexPaths takes an array of section & row that is NSIndexPath instance

```
- (IBAction)actionDeleteCell:(UIButton *)sender {

// below code for getting selected cell row and its section

UIView *view = sender.superview;
while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]]) view = view.superview;

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
indexPathForDeletion = [self.tableViewListViewVC indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"cell is in section %d, row %d", indexPathForDeletion.section, indexPathForDeletion.row);

//below code for deletion from your datasource and then delete from tableview

 [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPathForDeletion.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathForDeletion]];
}
```

Comment: @bhavya can you tell me how to do it using swift